# Expressing Vectors In Terms of Other Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

My professor asked us a few questions in class and asked us to think about them. He's going to reveal the solutions on Thursday, but I want to understand it before he talks about it on Thursday in greater detail. If anyone could explain any of the things below, it would be appreciated. Thanks in advance. (and if you can't, don't worry- I can ask the professor after class on Thursday)[image]

Comment: As for the work that I've done, I've noticed that since A is between 0 and 1, that must mean that UW is shorter than UV, and that AM is 3 times as long as XM, although by looking at the diagram it seems fairly obvious anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, we want $w-u=a(v-u)$, or more pleasantly $w=(1-a)u+av$.

This will of use in the second problem. Compute the point in the desired $2/3$ to $1/3$ position, and note that the answer is symmetrical.